# Intel XDK / Cordova: 'ContactFindOptions' is not defined

Tags: cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I'm trying to simulate a contact list with Intel XDK. But it is not working, showing the error:

**'ContactFindOptions' is not defined**

The Cordova Contacts plugin is installed in the project, but the problem persists, following images:

**--**
**-- Plugins:**
[image]

**--**
**-- Instance object and error message:**
[image]

In this way the application is not working, obviously.

> ?? Does it have something to do with those permissions **"READ_CONTACT"** and other permissions ??

Thank you!